# How can I make the label text on a Views Exposed Filter inline?

Tags: 7, views, theming

In Views 3, it's easy to make the labels of fields appear inline by adjusting the settings at `Format: Show: Settings`.

However, there appears to be no corresponding setting for Exposed Filters.  I tried to do it myself in CSS,  but adding:

`#edit-field-acc-gender-value-wrapper label`

gives me the horizontal alignment but not the vertical alignment, as you can see below:

[image]

How can I fix my CSS, or is there a better way to make the labels for Exposed Filters inline?

Answer (score 1):

You may give a top margin to the label:

```
#edit-field-acc-gender-value-wrapper label{
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

It is not the best way but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Compact Forms module. This will handle it with javascript, and works with any form - you simply configure the module with the ID of any forms you want it to apply to, e.g. user login, webforms etc.

http://drupal.org/project/compact_forms